# List animation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list that can have at least 5 items (between 6 and 20 depending on other settings) and I want to show the first 5 items from the list and when the button show more is clicked to show the rest of the list, but the occurrence of rest of the list should be animated, something like transition: height 1s. How can I do that?

```
function myComponent() {
  const list:string[] = []
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<boolean>(false)

function handleShowMore() {
    if (showMore) {
      setShowMore(false)
    } else {
      setShowMore(true)
    }
  }

return (
<div classname='container'>
    <ul>
         {list.slice(0, 5).map((item, index) => (
            <li>
               {item}
            </li>
         ))}

        { showMore &&
             list.slice(5).map((item, index) => (
               <li>
                {item}
               </li>
          ))}
    </ul>

   <button
         onClick={_ => handleShowMore()}>
         {showMore ? 'Show less' : 'Show more
   </button>
</div>
)
}
```